# Django - input octal for integer

Tags: django

I've got a model that includes an integer field that holds octal numbers.  I also have a ModelForm associated with that model.  I want to make it so the user can enter a number into the form that is already in octal.  Is there a nice way of doing this in Django?

Answer (score 0):

Note sure of what you mean with

> integer field that holds octal numbers

That's an integer, even if you want user to give octal values. Unless you store it as a string ?

One way would be to use a `CharField` with a regexp for the validation (like `[0-7]+`), and a callback `<field>_validate` (using `isnumeric()` to check it is a correct number).

You can also write a custom field:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-model-fields/

Comment: I mean an integerfield that that I use specifically for numbers that will be output as octal numbers.  I was hoping there was an easy way to have the user enter a string and then convert to octal before putting it into the integerfield without having to make my own field.